# How do I fix "stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - (error reading rustc version)" on ubuntu

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am a beginner in the programming field and I am trying to install rust on ubuntu and I keep getting `stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - (error reading rustc version)`. Attached is a picture of the error. Ho0w do I resolve this please?[An image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGOiP.png)

I tried to install Rust on ubuntu on windows 11. I was expecting that rust would be installed successfully, but that wasn't the case. I instead got an error code that read "stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - (error reading rustc version)"

Comment: Check if you already have Rust installed from some source, and uninstall it first.

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: What steps did you take for installing? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).